# GOLANG SQL Syntax error with timestamp errors with dates between from to?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I have a problem with my SQL query:

```
    rows, err := r.db.Query(
        `SELECT products.*, user_activities.action_id, user_activities.created_at 
        FROM products JOIN user_activities on (
            user_activities.action_id=$1 AND 
            user_activities.product_id=products.id AND 
            user_activities.created_at between $2 and $3);)`,
        action_id, "2022-08-24", "2022-08-26")
```

Also tried with this syntax:

```
user_activities.created::date_at between $2::date and $3::date)
```

I have 3 tables and try to write a SQL query, but I get an error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"

Here are my tables:

```
    database.Pdb.Exec(`CREATE TABLE products (
                        id CHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
                        name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
                        description VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
                        price FLOAT(8) NOT NULL,
                        category_id CHAR(36) NOT NULL
                    );`)

    database.Pdb.Exec(`CREATE TABLE categories (
                        id CHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
                        name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
                    );`)

    database.Pdb.Exec(`CREATE TABLE actions (
                        id CHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
                        name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
                    );`)

    database.Pdb.Exec(`CREATE TABLE user_activities (
                        id CHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
                        action_id CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
                        product_id CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
                        created_at TIMESTAMP,
                        FOREIGN KEY (action_id) REFERENCES actions(id),
                        FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(id)                           
                    );`)
```

Problems with my dates string.

Thank you for all who can give me an advise or help me.

P.S.: all my two variants working perfect in postgresql playground https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jKbfxMHfWBTScWnPCmtbP9/0

Comment: `);)` ? You need to remove that trailing `)`

Comment: Another problem is that the parameters are strings, not dates.  Use eg `time.Parse` to generate Time instances and pass these as parameters

Comment: Yet another problem is that `JOIN .. ON` contains expressions that should be part of `WHERE`. The JOIN expression should be just `FROM products JOIN user_activities on user_activities.product_id=products.id`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you, you are totally right. The problem solved!